# Registering a private endpoint in Azure private DNS automatically using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I have an existing private DNS zone called **privatelink.file.core.windows.net** that is linked to a virtual network.

I have created a Terraform template that creates a storage account and a private endpoint for said storage account that connects to the virtual network mentioned above. When the resources are created I've noticed that it doesn't register in the private DNS zone automatically. Instead I've had to manually create a private DNS A record, I would prefer this to happen automatically, how does one do this?

**Storage Account Creation**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "st" {
    name = var.st.name
    resource_group_name = var.rg_shared_name
    location = var.rg_shared_location
    account_tier = var.st.tier
    account_replication_type = var.st.replication
}
```

**Private Endpoint Creation**

```
# PRIVATE ENDPOINT FOR STORAGE ACCOUNT
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "pe" {
    name = var.pe.name
    resource_group_name = var.rg_shared_name
    location = var.rg_shared_location
    subnet_id = var.subnet_id

    private_service_connection {
      name = "test"
      private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.st.id
      is_manual_connection = false
      subresource_names = ["file"]
    }
}
```

**Manual Creation of DNS Record**

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "st_fqdn" {
  name = azurerm_storage_account.st.name
  zone_name = "privatelink.file.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = "rg-hub-shared-core-dns-uks-001"
  ttl = 300
  records = ["172.17.208.4"]
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: @marcin, no, I don't get any errors. It creates both the private endpoint and storage account but does not register automatically in Azure private DNS, unless I add a manual entry using the azure_private_dns_a_record resource block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolve this issue, I missed **private_dns_zone_group** within the **azurerm_private_endpoint** resource block. Once I added this code it populated Azure private DNS automatically.

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint

The code below is what I changed and added the section **private_dns_zone_group**.

```
# PRIVATE ENDPOINT FOR STORAGE ACCOUNT
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "pe" {
    name = var.pe.name
    resource_group_name = var.rg_shared_name
    location = var.rg_shared_location
    subnet_id = var.subnet_id

    private_dns_zone_group {
      name = "add_to_azure_private_dns"
      private_dns_zone_ids = ["/subscriptions/d5f2dcf8-ab3f-47aa-9ec3-9c5aba4b909f/resourceGroups/rg-hub-shared-core-dns-uks-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.file.core.windows.net"]
    }

    private_service_connection {
      name = "connect_to_storage_account"
      private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.st.id
      is_manual_connection = false
      subresource_names = ["file"]
    }
}
```